# Cannot read/burn Cd-R disks

Tags: cd-drive, cd-ripping

I cannot read CD-R disks with data on and have an error in Brasero when I try to burn CD-R disks. All other disks work fine including CD-RW. Is there a problem I can fix before I try buying a new drive?

Thanks.

Comment: Have tried anything else besides Brasero?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I cannot add another Braero type program at the moment. But I did try slax and kde does not let me record on Cd-r - it said OPC failed: burner  does not like the medium - or read cd-r disks with data on. And in XP (it's an older pc) when I put a Cd-r in the drive with data on it says d:\ is not accessible incorrect function.